# Precedence in saving in Django Admin with TabularInline

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have 2 models Owner and Item.

```
class Owner(admin.ModelAdmin):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Item(admin.ModelAdmin):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

With the following rules:

1) If the Owner `is_active` is `False`, an `Item` can't be come active
2) If an `Owner` that `is_active` was `True` becomes `False` all the `Item(s)` `is_active` become `False`

**Rule 1, in Item Model:**

```
def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    if self.is_active:
        if not self.owner.is_active:
            raise ValidationError(
                {'is_active': 'The Owner need to be checked an validated first'})
    return self.is_active
```

**Rule 2, in  Model: (with help from the stackoverflow):**

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if the active state was changed and is False
        if self.__original_is_active != self.is_active and self.is_active is False:
            # update does direct changes in database doesn't call save or signals
            self.items.update(is_active=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**The issue:**

I added the `Item Model` in `Owner Admin` as  `TabularInline`.

For Rule 2, when I toggle `is_active` for `Owner` from `True` To `False`  and try to save, the Rule1 (ValidationError) appear, and can't be saved.

This is strange for me because the update to the product `is_active` is done before the `Owner Form` is saved, so it should have the previous value.

I think that `is_active` for `Item` is updated to `False`, but on save tries to do it again `True`(because remains this way in the UI), but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your problem and tested. After a little debugging I found following

**The problem**

When you save `Owner` model, admin form validates it and performs `full_clean` on it. When `full_clean` is called over a model instance, updated values are assigned to it whether it is saved in db or not. It means `is_active` value for Owner is False now (but not saved in db yet).

Before saving this instance to db, django admin cleans all formset instances and assign new values to them (if updated any). This the point where you are trying to validate `Item` instances.

Updated (but not saved in db) owner has been assigned to all `Item` instances. And here code fails because `Item` instances have updated owner instance which has updated `is_active` value.

**The solution**

I suggest you to use same hack for condition checking you used to check if the value of `is_active` for owner has been changed or not. Just make `__original_is_active` field from private to protected and use it for validation like this

```
def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    if self.is_active:
        if not self.owner._original_is_active:
            raise ValidationError(
                {'is_active': 'The Owner need to be checked an validated first'})
    return self.is_active
```

Owner instance will have updated value for `is_active` but also initial value cached in `_original_is_active`.

I hope this will solve your confusion and problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Django admin, When you save a form. First it is validated and then save method is called.

You can either override your default django form. For eg:

```
class CompanyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        self.instance.products.update(is_active=False)
        return self.cleaned_data

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CompanyAdminForm
```

Or you can change your Product clean method to

```
def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    if self.is_active and not self.company.is_active:
        self.is_active = False
    return self.is_active
```

Comment: the first solution with the Form is not working at all, the second solution works for inline products, but when I move to the Products Detail I can set is_active as True with no issue even if Company is_Active is_False(because I replace my navigation). Somehow I need to combine both; I don't I can use 2 cases depending if is inline or not